# how to fadeout message in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

```
<script>
  function Ctrl($scope, $window, $timeout) {
    $scope.greeting = 'Hello, World!';
    $scope.showGreeting = false;
    $scope.doGreeting = function() {
       $scope.msg="hi";
       $scope.showGreeting = true;
       $timeout(function(){
          $scope.showGreeting = false;
       }, 10000);
    };
  }
</script>
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <input type="text" ng-model="greeting" />
  <button ng-click="doGreeting()">click</button>
  <span ng-show="showGreeting ">{{msg}}</span>
</div>
```

This code shows a message when the user clicks on the button for 10 seconds and then hide. Here the message is hiding fast.I want it to hide it slowly (like fadeout in jquery). Can you help me please how I can achieve this in angularJS.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this module (https://github.com/marcorinck/angular-growl) for my messages which can fade-out maybe you can try.

Answer (score 0):

Check out ngAnimate. Try adding this to your css, and inject ngAnimate into your module.

```
span.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try **angularStrap** alerts.

[AngularStrap](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/##alerts)

Hope this will help you!